# parallelization of python code on the server

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I need advice or even examples of possible solutions to parallelize python code.

Task Description:

1. There is a group of files (we'll call this whole group of files, for simplicity, a constructor), the work of which is controlled inside the main file (inside the iterative process in the main file);
2. in this group of files there are three files (let's call this group of files, for simplicity, group_a), which, I would like to be executed in parallel and there are files (let's call this group of files, for simplicity, group_b) for, strictly, sequential execution;
3. when work with group_a is completed, work is performed with group_b and only after that in the main file there is a transition to the next iteration and so on for each iteration;
   3a. each file in group_a and group_b is a Python function;
   3b. the return data from group_a and group_b is produced inside the main file (also a Python function);
   3c. sets of arguments for working with group_a and group_b are different;
4. The execution of a group of files (from point No. 1) is planned to be carried out on the server. The server has multiple cores;

Questions :

1. how to get a list of numbers, or something similar, of cores (here I will digress: before deploying the designer on the server, I plan to do parallelization and multithreading on a working computer, Windows OS)
2. How to scatter the execution of files in group_a on different kernels / groups of kernels?
   2a. Since there are guaranteed to be more cores on the server than files in group_a, how else can each file in group_a be parallelized within the group of cores? For example , 3 files and 12 cores . The assignment is made: the first file - 4 cores, the second file - 4 cores, the third file - 4 cores. This creates three streams. Within each thread , file execution is parallelized into 4 cores . And only when all three threads have completed their work, only then is work with group_b performed.

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing?  Because of the global interpreter lock, multithreading in Python is only a net gain if your workload is I/O bound.  For compute-bound workloads, only one thread at a time can run.

Comment: `os.cpu_count()` returns number of cores. Also, your question is very confusing. You seem to be using multiprocessing and multithreading interchangeably. They both have different use-cases and very different from each other. Threading is for i/o based work while multiprocessing is for cpu-bound tasks